# Character code pages on Windows 7

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm facing a major issue with the code pages on my computer.
In the `Text Services and Input Languages` I choose to use `English (United States) - US` 
And for Greek Language I choose to use `Greek Polytonic`
When I run my project I use the following code to validate the characters are typed

```
Public Shared Function ValidateChar(ByVal AsciiChar As String, ByVal CharTable As String, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) As Boolean
        Dim ConvChar As Integer = CUInt(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(AsciiChar))
        Dim ConvCharW As Integer = CUInt(Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(AsciiChar))

        ValidateChar = False

        Select Case CharTable
            Case GrEn
                Select Case ConvChar
                    Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 182, 184 To 186, 188, 190 To 254, 8
                        ValidateChar = True
                End Select
End Function
```

When I type the Greek character `λ` small lambda the `ConvChar` gives me the number 63 and when I type the English character `c` it gives me the number 99
The issue here is not only to find the character numbers for my computer; but also to control the characters set for any computer.
Is there any Tip to assist me on this?

Finaly I use this code as a solution on my computer:

```
Public Shared Function ValidateChar(ByVal AsciiChar As String, ByVal CharTable As String, 
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) As Boolean
            Dim ConvChar As Integer = CUInt(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(AsciiChar))
            Dim ConvCharW As Integer = CUInt(Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(AsciiChar))

            ValidateChar = False

            Select Case CharTable
                Case GrEn
                    Select Case ConvCharW
                        Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 913 To 937, 945 To 969, 940 To 943, 972 To 974, 8147, 8163, 8
                            ValidateChar = True
                    End Select
                Case GrNEn
                    Select Case ConvCharW
                        Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 913 To 937, 945 To 969, 940 To 943, 972 To 974, 8147, 8163, 8
                            ValidateChar = True
                    End Select
    End Function
```

But even so I haven't solved the problem which I'll have when my project will run on another computer with deferent windows.

Comment: The letter λ is not an ASCII character.  So you get 63, the ASCII code for '?'.  Clearly you already figured out that you should not use the legacy Asc but use AscW instead so it is unclear why you persist in using Asc.

Comment: Yes I've done that, and solve my computer issue. But what about another computer with other code pages and other windows version. And more of it what about a MAC. How can I control my project to use the same code page any time.

Comment: .NET uses Unicode, code pages are a relic from the previous century.

Comment: @HansPassant Please Hans post your answer properly in order to give you my credits.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()`. Try converting your Unicode text to a `Byte` - although it will give you two-byte pairs for each character (as Unicode is UTF16LE).